# Given any arbitrary triangle, is it possible to conclude that the length of a median is less than 2 of the sides?

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, triangles

Below is a picture of a triangle, and I'm trying to figure out if the following is true, and if so how to prove it. Thank you.

d_ax < d_ab and d_ax < d_ac

[image]

Comment: Keep $B,C$ fixed, drag $A$ upwards, and watch what happens.

Comment: @Waslim Your claim is not true! Actually you can create a triangle in which a median is larger than two of the sides (one of them is the side of the median)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Why not writing the equations - this is a copy of what I said. Adding the equations would make it a proper answer!

Comment: I said that you could build the triangle as you did.

Answer (score 1):

The claim does not hold for a general triangle. Let fix the angle $\alpha$ between the sides $b$ and $c$.

Then the length square of the median drawn from $A$ is:

$$
m_A^2=\frac{b^2+c^2+2bc\cos\alpha}4
$$
so that
$$
m_A^2>c^2\iff b^2+2bc\cos\alpha-3c^2>0\iff \frac bc>\sqrt{3+\cos^2\alpha}-\cos\alpha,
$$
which is certainly possible for **any** angle $\alpha$.